# Meaning of the notation $z = [x^T, y^T]^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, vectors

If $T$ is the transpose we have for two vectors $(ab)^T=b^Ta^T$, but what is the meaning of $[x^T, y^T]^T$ in the following?

> The concatenation $z = [x^T, y^T]^T$ of two column vectors $x \in 
> \mathbb R ^n$, $y \in \mathbb R^m$ is also denoted $z = (x, y)$, so that $z \in  \mathbb R^{n+m}$.

Comment: It means to stack two vectors on top of each other. You have a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ whose first $n$ entries are the entries of $x$ and the last $m$ entries are the entries of $y$.

Comment: This is simply a way of writing $z = \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ that avoids using too much vertical space